# Python selenium bindings, picking out <td> elements

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Python Selenium bindings and testing a webserver.  I am trying to assert the presence of the text "Regression" and "Regression Test".  Does anyone have a clue how to do it?  Here is what I see when I inspect the element I am interested in:

```
<tr class="selectedRow " data-getaction="[0,0,85,0,0,115,0,0,101,0,0,114,0,0,84,0,0,97,0,0,98,0,0,108,0,0,101,0,0,65,0,0,99,0,0,116,0,0,105,0,0,111,0,0,110,1,0,0,83,0,0,101,0,0,108,0,0,101,0,0,99,0,0,116,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4]">
<td>Regression</td>
<td>Regression Test</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all `td`s inside the element, assert there are both "Regression" and "Regression Test" td element texts. For example:

```
values = ["Regression", "Regression Test"]

selected_row = driver.find_element_by_class_name('selectedRow')
tds = [td.text for td in selected_row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')]

self.assertTrue(all(value in tds for value in values))
```

where `driver` is an instance of selenium `WebDriver`. Using `self.assertTrue` assuming this is placed inside of a `unittest.TestCase`.

Hope that helps.